# Python - MySQLi parametized query with %d

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

This might be a question that has already been answered but I haven't found anything relating to it.

I think I might have a unique scenario, I need to add a parameter to the query for the LIMIT clause. Stack Overflow consider:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `v_someview` WHERE `id` = %s LIMIT %s;"
x.execute(query,(str(id_variable),str(limit_variable))
```

Now it comes back with:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''5'' at line 1

Am I supposed to use %d or is this specific use discouraged?

Note: the field from which this limit variable I drawn is a `tinyint`, so I don't see anyway for an SQL injection attack but I would still like to use parametized query with it.

Use with %d stops execution and bypasses the catch block:

```
try:
  query = """SELECT * FROM `v_someview` WHERE `id` = %s LIMIT %d;"""
  x.execute(query,(str(id),int(l)))
except Exception as ex:
  #some code
```

The library in use is MySQLi.
Variable 'x' is a cursor.
Variable 'id_variable' is an int with the id

Comment: Have you tried it with `%d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it myself by using:

```
try:
  query = """SELECT * FROM `v_someview` WHERE `id` = %s LIMIT %s;"""
  x.execute(query,(str(id),int(l)))
except Exception as ex:
  #some code
```

So I'm declaring that i'm going to use a string (%s) but casting that parameter to an int().

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: You may be able to delete your answer instead of vandalizing it. Should be next to the edit button.